# How to use variable on looping in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some `varchar` variables like this:

```
@var1='data a', 
@var2='data b',
@var3='data c', 
...,
@varn='data n'
```

I want to insert these variable on looping script.

```
DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 1

WHILE(@counter <= n)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [table] 
    SET [header] 
    WHERE data = [@var1-n]

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
GO
```

How to make @var1 - @varn can use with loop on **[@var1-n]**?

Comment: The code in your question can't run. What are you setting the `Header` column value to? Also, Sql works best on set based operations. Loops should be avoided whenever possible. Please edit your question to create a [mcve] so that it could be answered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplest** and most "relational" way would be to use the tools you have available in a relational database - **tables**.

Put your new values into a table (can be a table variable), and then update your base table with a **single, set-based** statement.

Something like this:

```
-- declare the table to hold the keys and new values
DECLARE @NewValues TABLE (Data VARCHAR(20), NewHeader VARCHAR(50))

-- insert new data into this table variable instead of having n separate variables
INSERT INTO @NewValues (Data, NewHeader)
VALUES ('data a', 'New Header a'), ('data b', 'New Header b'), 
       ....., ('data n', 'New Header n');

-- update your base table in a SINGLE set-based statement
UPDATE dbo.YourBaseTable
SET Header = nv.NewHeader
FROM @NewValues nv 
WHERE dbo.YourBaseTable.Data = nv.Data
```

One nice simple statement, can handle any number of rows in the `@NewValues` table variable .....

Comment: I think that's what I need.
I 've tried it, and it worked . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There's no natively slick way to dynamically choose a variable. You'd either have to come up with some ugly case statement, dynamic SQL, etc. but perhaps the most elegant way would be to cache the variables in a table and then you'd be able to select data dynamically based on whatever the iteration calls for. Also, there is probably a way to solve your issue without doing a while loop and making it a set based operation.

Comment: is there any other way to enter "data 1" - "data n" into the loop ?

thanks!

Comment: You can use some dynamic SQL wizardry if you really wanted to do it but that would really be disgusting looking. You should try to write it without using a loop and using a set based operation.